# Mental Math Question

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Saw this on an online interview thread.

You have 4 coins, and you get $\$1$ for each heads. If you had the option to reflip all of the coins, what is the expected value of this game?

My attempt: expected value of one flip is $\$2$, but if you flip and get $\$0$ or $\$1$, you will reflip. If $X$ equals the value of first flip:
$$E(game) = P(X=0)*E(1 flip) + P(X=1)*E(1 flip) + P(X=2)*$2 + P(X=3)*$3 + P(X=4)*$4:\\
P(X=0) = \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4 = \frac{1}{16} = P(X=1)\\
P(X=0) + P(X=1) = \frac{1}{8}\\
P(X=2) = \left._4C_2\right.\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4 = \frac{1}{4}\\
\frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{4} = \frac{3}{8}\\
E(game) = \frac{1}{8}*$2 + \frac{1}{4}*$2 + \frac{3+4}{2}*\frac{5}{8} = \frac{12}{16}+\frac{35}{16}= \frac{47}{16}$$

Comment: at first round : $p(X_1 = n) = \frac{C_4^n}{16}$, expectancy $$\mathbb{E}[X_1] = \sum_n n p(X_1 = n) = 2$$
and at second round **if there is one**, same probability $p(X_2 = n) = \frac{\displaystyle C_4^n}{16}$, same expectancy $\mathbb{E}[X_2]=2$. now, how would you maximise the overall expectancy ? let's choose as strategy to reflip the coins for a second round **only if** the expectancy for the second round is greater than what we got at the first round, and see if there is a way to maximize even more the overall expectancy

Comment: Can you reflip just the ones you want, or do you have to reflip all or none?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Do I have to return all the coins if I reflip?  I'd just keep reflipping unitl I flip 4 heads.

Comment: this is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your option is only to reflip all the coins together and only once:

If you flip once, the expectation is $2$.  You should therefore reflip if you get $0$ or $1$ on the first flip.  Your expectation is then $\frac 5{16}\cdot 2$ (reflip) $+\frac 6{16} \cdot 2 + \frac 4{16} \cdot 3 + \frac 1{16} \cdot 4=\frac {10+12+12+4}{16}=\frac {38}{16}$

If your option is to reflip once any coins you want, you can consider each coin separately.  For each coin, the expectation is $\frac 34$ as you get $1$ unless you get two tails.  The total expectation is then $3$.

Answer (score 1):

Your first line is correct, but notice on the first flip, there are $_4C_0$ ways of getting zero heads, $_4C_1$ ways of getting one head, etc. The probabilities for the number of heads on the first flip are then
$$P(x=0)=\frac{1}{16}\qquad P(x=1)=\frac{4}{16}\qquad P(x=2)=\frac{6}{16}\\
P(x=3)=\frac{4}{16}\qquad P(x=4)=\frac{1}{16}$$
and your first line reduces to
$$E(game)=\frac{1}{16}*2+\frac{4}{16}*2+\frac{6}{16}*2+\frac{4}{16}*3+\frac{1}{16}*4=\frac{38}{16}=\$2.375$$

Answer (score 1):

Break the first round in half: Flip *two* coins and pause. If both coins land Tails, you might as well skip the second half of the first round and proceed directly to the second round, flipping all four coins, with expected payoff $\$2$.  If both coins land Heads, you can't expect to do better on a second round, so simply complete the first round, for an expected payoff of $\$3$.  Finally, if the two coins split Heads and Tails, go ahead and flip the other two coins, then reflip all four coins unless the final two coins both land Heads; in this case the expected payoff (in dollars) is ${3\over4}\cdot2+{1\over4}\cdot3={9\over4}$.  So the expected value of the game is

$${1\over4}\cdot2+{1\over4}\cdot3+{1\over2}\cdot{9\over4}={19\over8}=\$2.375$$

Remark: It's worth noting that in this approach you sometimes "accept "an equal split ($2$ Heads and $2$ Tails) from the first round and sometimes "reject" it (i.e., flip the four coins again).  This is part of what makes the calculations here as simple as they are.